# How to keep artifacts directory during the multi-configuration build in TFS?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, multi-configuration

I have a solution with multiple projects where some are web apps.  I have set up a multi-configuration build in TFS vNext that builds the single app, creates an MSDeploy package, gets the proper staging configuration files and add or replaces the files in the package archive file.

I'd like to use the deployment files created as artifacts to be used in a Release Management pipeline. The problem is that the artifacts directory is purged before each build (i.e. build of a web application). At the end, only the artefacts of the last app that was built are left there.

I can certainly configure the step to copy the artifacts somewhere else, but then the question is how to delete it only at the very start of the build (and by that I mean the build of all projects).

Is there a way how to disable purging of the artefacts directory or how to perform an operation only at the beginning of the build? Has anyone similar experience?

Comment: I encounter the same situation, what was your solution ? Copy to UNC or local folder ? And how do you clean it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Publish Artifacts" task to store the artifacts in a UNC location or in TFS itself so they're available for release.